# Why isn't my datagrid updating?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have an object that has as one of its properties, a List.  I want to bind a datagrid to that list, such that when I add objects to the grid, the datagrid updates.  I tried:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = myObject.MyList;
```

but when I update the datasource with new rows, the grid doesn't update.

Then I tried:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = null;
myDataGrid.DataSource = myObject.MyList;
```

Calling the above code every time I added an item.  This resulted in an error when clicking on the grid (specifically, index -1 has no data, something to do with the datagridview.get_current internally.  Happens despite the fact that I'm not clicking the -1st row).

So then I tried:

```
myDataGrid.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSoruce",myObject,"MyList",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

That didn't reflect the updates either, so I added:

```
myDataGrid.DataBindings[0].ReadValue();
```

whenever I added an item, but it has no effect either.  I feel like I'm circling around a simpler solution to this problem, but I can't seem to find it.  Any pro tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to already know this, but you want to use a BindingList if at all possible here. Any hamfisted attempt to make a List function like a BindingList is just going to be a lot more pain than simply copying the elements from a List you already have to a BindingList.

Comment: Yea, finding out there WAS a BindingList<T> and realizing the difference between that and a List<T> was the "moment of breakthrough" there.

Answer (score 0):

If I changed my type from List to BindingList, all the problems go away and the grid autoupdates as expected.